# Automatic resolution when converting PDF to images

Tags: linux, pdf, images, resolution

I have some scanned PDF files that I want to process using ScanTailor. To do that I need to extract images (as TIFF). I have been using GhostScript as follows:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffgray -r400x400 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile="file0000.tiff" "input.pdf"
```

The problem is I don't know what is the resolution of the original images in PDF. Is there any way to make GhostScript to adapt its resolution based on the images in the PDF file? Or is there any other free Linux software that can do that?

[Adobe Acrobat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7ef2.w.html#WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7eed.w) does that:

> Colorspace/**Resolution** Specifies a color space and resolution for the output file. You can **let Acrobat determine these settings automatically**.

Answer (score 1):

The pdfimages from poppler-utils extracts images from pdf files, it saves them as PBM for monochrome images and PPM for non-monochrome images but you can make it output jpg instead. If that does not suite you then you can use pdfimages -list to get a list of images and their information including resolutions.